# Custom markers in Plotly Dash legend

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have two traces on the graph, one of which is a Candlestick graph and the other is a Bar chart with green and red bars. The automatically generated legend looks like the following:

[image: Current legend]

However, I find it a little bit misleading and would like to rotate a marker for the Candlestick graph and depict two colors of the Bar chart. So, the legend should look like the following:

[image: Desired legend]

Is it possible to achieve it and how?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible via plotly currently. Plotly's legend symbols are 1-1 with their marker counterparts such that the user can essentially only change the legend via the markers characteristics. I.e. Making the bar graph purple will make the legend symbol purple, but you can't directly change the legend to purple without changing the bar graph to be purple.

You should post on the plotly forum as well. Sometimes the devs will find work around solutions for things not natively possible on plotly.

https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/

https://plotly.com/python/legend/

Comment: Yes, I have also addressed the question to the community, but haven't received the answer yet https://community.plotly.com/t/custom-markers-in-legend/50587